# Открыть csv файл разделенный ; в Excel из C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

Нужно открыть файл csv с разделителем ";" из C# в Excel.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Excel.Application oExcel = new Excel.Application();


            oExcel.Visible = true;

            Excel.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
            Excel._Workbook oBook = null;


            string path2 = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            path2 = path2 + "\\Worksheet02.csv";
            //Open the file, using the 'path' variable
            oBook = oBooks.Open(path2, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
}
```

Excel запускается. Файл csv открывается, но не разделенный по столбцам. Если подставить файл csv с разделителем "," то откроется и файл будет разделен по столбцам.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что бы файл с разделителем ";" открывался в Excel разделенный по столбцам?

Comment: Не знаю как работает эта магия, хотя и догадываюсь, но почитайте [тут](https://superuser.com/a/730509), оно реально работает. Вы же можете сделать копию файла и добавить ему необходимый заголовок перед отправкой в excel? А заголовок может содержать указание какой разделитель использовать, хоть букву туда пропишите, хоть иероглиф.

Comment: Спасибо. Это работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо rdorn за наводку.
Нужно добавить в начало csv файла первую строку вида:

```
sep=;
```

То есть файл источник должен выглядеть так.

```
sep=;
Столбец1;Столбец2; Столбец3;Столбец4;Столбец5
...
СтолбецX1;СтолбецX2; СтолбецX3;СтолбецX4;СтолбецX5
```

И код любой заработает, и через OpenText и через Open.

Answer (score 0):

```
Excel.Application ex = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbooks wbs = ex.Workbooks;

wbs.OpenText(path,
    DataType:Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, 
    Semicolon: true);
```

ответ найден по запросу "import csv delimiter excel c#"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611945/4423545